# How can I remotely turn on and off the heat to my ice house within a 2000 meter (1.243 mile) radius?

Tags: electrical

How can I remotely turn on and off the heat to my ice house within a 2000 meter (1.243 mile) radius?

In order to turn on and off the heat at the ice house,
I would have to turn on the propane tank outside and then go inside and press the on button on the heater.

My current plans are to create a machine that would turn on propane tank outside and another machine to press the on button inside. I would connect the two machines to a wireless receiver. From this site (http://www.rfcontrolsystem.com/index.php?cPath=173), I learned that in order to extend the range, I would have to use a wireless relay (I'm not certain if it would be AC or DC). I know I have to use a 5000 meter relay because of interference. I would like to have two remote controls for one receiver, but I'm not sure if that's what channel means in 2 channel versus 4 channel AC/DC power supply in the 5000 meter remote control kits.

My main questions are:

Would a receiver online time and the two machines take up too much battery power that the project wouldn't be worth the 15-20 mins of waiting in the trailer till it warms up?

Is this the proper plan of attack for a project like this?

Would I use AC or DC power?

Does having two remote controls mean having two channels?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: how big is the ice house? ... do you really need to have it preheated before you get there?

Comment: Hire someone to go out and turn it on for you when you text them

Comment: Is there any mains electricity at the ice house?  Are you politically opposed to solar panels and batteries for any reason?  What kind of budget?

Comment: If one of your two machines fails, will you create an unsafe condition? For example, I'm not sure how your heater works but presumably it burns propane. What happens if the fire goes out but the tank remains open? Is the ice house going to fill with propane?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a DIY Home Improvement project, or related, as defined in the help center.

Comment: Don't you have any kids?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a clear line of sight for the 1.2 miles and always come from the same direction every time? I would use 2.4GHz WiFi with high gain directional antennas and either a Raspberry Pi or Arduino to do the rest. This would give you 2-way communication instead of the 1-way with a remote.

2 channel means 1 remote controls 2 relays. If you get something in the 300-500 MHz frequency, then you could use a UHF TV antenna to increase the directional range more than the omni-directional will give you.

If you're running this off a battery, then make sure everything is DC. Using an inverter to make AC ftom DC is inefficient.

Battery consumption should be less than 50ma, so just power it off a deep cycle marine battery and add a solar panel on the roof or a wind generator if you need longer duration. If you're an ice fisherman you probably have a boat you can borrow the battery from.

Comment: Even better (assuming phone coverage is OK), get a [3G PiHat](https://sixfab.com/product/raspberry-pi-3g-4glte-base-shield-v2/), and you can text it.